# Dlls not deployed to GAC - SharePoint 2013, Visual Studio 2012, .Net FW 4.5

Tags: sharepoint, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5, sharepoint-2013

When I create a simple SharePoint 2013 project in Visual Studio 2012 and I want to deploy it, it deploys fine, but Dll is not in the Global Assembly Cache. In Advanced tab, I have added project assembly to be deployed.

[image]

In different test I set **Assembly Deployment Target** option to ***GlobalAssemblyCache***, and **Include Assembly In Package** to ***True***, and removed dll from package described in first scenario.

[image]

Project .NET FW version is 4.5. Machine is virtual machine 64bit, Windows Server 2008. I have tried also to change project's platform target to X64 and Any CPU without no luck.

I have tried to add dll manually using gacutil tool, and it is not deployed as well. Could it be something related to 4.5 framework? I can't also deploy manually any Dlls made in 4.5 but all other work.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You have overwhelming evidence that the way you check that it got stored in the GAC is wrong.  Which you didn't mention.  It is not in c:\windows\assembly anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm checking it in c:\windows\assembly, it should be there, right? I did test with two explorer windows, one shows GAC, other shows my DLLs. I can move to GAC only DLLs which are not made in .net 4.5. When moving .net 4.5 DLLs to GAC nothing happens. It looks like 4.5 DLLs cannot be installed to GAC for some reason.

Comment: +1 for the effort into the Q, lots of details, listing what you have tried etc.

Comment: Hi could you tell me what happens when we set 'Include Assembly In Package' to 'True' AND remove the DLLs from the package, please?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

> I'm checking it in c:\windows\assembly, it should be there, right?

No, that's the directory for the GAC in .NET versions 1.0 through 3.5.  It was moved in .NET 4.0 and up, now located in c:\windows\microsoft.net\assembly.  You can browse that directory with Explorer, the shell extension handler that flattened the view of the GAC directories is no longer used.  If the assembly doesn't contain any unmanaged code then start in the GAC_MSIL directory, you'll have few problems locating the actual file from there.

Comment: That is exactly what I was searching for. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Hans Is there any reason why Microsoft adapted this change? And i do have problems like you said..Any reference that you could give me to resolve those problems?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, and I think an IISReset fixed it?

I made changes to my event receiver.
In the package, I added the assembly from Project output like you have.
I set the "Include assembly in Package" to False on the Project properties.

I deployed, but my event receiver changes did not look like they were happening.

I ran an IIS Reset, and could then see my changes.